# I can no longer access PHPMyAdmin after I set a password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to connect to my MySQL DB remotely. According to the tutorial, it will require me to have a password (by default, I don't have one) when I ran the script to change the password, I can no longer access the server.

I've been following several tutorials and most of them mentioned `config.inc.php` but the path says `wamp/`. I dont have a WAMP folder on my drive `C:` so how can I fix this step by step? And does PHPMyAdmin have a login page?

Comment: Sounds like you locked yourself out. We can't do step-by-step help here, and further, this isn't a programming question but one about getting software on your computer working. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: After changing the password, can you access MySQL from from the command prompt (on the local machine) without using phpMyAdmin? If so, there might be hope!

Comment: i found the answer here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSMRmvIUhdE